# Where can I learn ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I really want to get more into video/audio encoding and decoding, and I’ve heard that ffmpeg is a good tool, but I can’t find any good tutorials for it. Does anyone know a good way to learn it?

Comment: Learn by doing, Just start by encoding a video.

Answer (score 10):

I think this tutorial is very well written and illustrated https://github.com/leandromoreira/ffmpeg-libav-tutorial

Answer (score 7):

#### Browse trough these links:

- [ffmpeg Encoding and Editing Course](http://slhck.info/ffmpeg-encoding-course) by Werner Robitza

  [image: ffmpeg Encoding and Editing Course]
- [ffmpeg examples](https://hhsprings.bitbucket.io/docs/programming/examples/ffmpeg/index.html) by hhsprings (bitbucket.io)

  [image: ffmpeg examples]
- [ffmpeg book](http://www.astro-electronic.de/FFmpeg_Book.pdf) by Michael Koch

  [image: ffmpeg book]
- [ffmprovisr](https://amiaopensource.github.io/ffmprovisr/)

  [image: ffmprovisr]

#### Books:

- FFmpeg Basics: Multimedia handling with a fast audio and video encoder by Frantisek Korbel

  [image: FFmpeg Basics]
- Learn to Produce Video with FFmpeg in 30 Minutes or Less by Jan Ozer

  [image: Learn to Produce Video with FFmpeg in 30 Minutes or Less]

Answer (score 1):

## Official Sources

#### Resources

- [FFmpeg Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html) - Start here.
- [FFmpeg Wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/#CommunityContributedDocumentation) - Has many articles to supplement the documentation.
- [FFmpeg Twitter](https://twitter.com/FFmpeg) - Provides occasional, random tips.
- [Doxygen](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/index.html) - Library and API documentation
- `doc/examples` in the FFmpeg source code

#### Help

- #ffmpeg IRC channel on Freenode
- [ffmpeg-user mailing list](https://ffmpeg.org/contact.html) for help using the command-line tools (`ffmpeg`, `ffprobe`, `ffplay`)
- [libav-user mailing list](https://ffmpeg.org/contact.html) for help using the libraries (libavcodec, libavformat, etc)

#### Development

See [FFmpeg Developer Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/developer.html), hang out in the #ffmpeg-devel IRC channel, and subscribe to the [ffmpeg-devel mailing list](https://ffmpeg.org/contact.html).

---

## Stack Exchange

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ffmpeg), [Super User](https://superuser.com/tags/ffmpeg), and [Video.SE](https://video.stackexchange.com/tags/ffmpeg) all have many `ffmpeg` usage questions. Searching these sites probably already have the answer you're looking for.

You can use the search bar with the [ffmpeg](/questions/tagged/ffmpeg) tag, such as:

```
[ffmpeg] adding silent audio
```

---

## reddit

There is an active subreddit at [r/ffmpeg](https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/).

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I fear that this could sound like self-promotion since I am linking to my own course. I sincerely apologize for that, but I do believe it is indeed very much relevant to this question and I think it adds value as an answer since this kind of introductory courses were not mentioned in other answers, nor I could find such courses elsewhere myself.*

I have greatly benefitted from the resources listed in the other answers. But I also found myself often in the same situation as the OP, since most of the resources I found were very detailed reference-like documentations which can be a bit difficult to go through for a beginner in audio/video processing like me that I was. I looked for a tutorial-style basic introduction to the concepts, but could not really find one. Years later, when I had ample opportunity and time to work with FFmpeg and had a clearer picture of the concepts, I put together a course on Udemy with diagrams, examples, and hands-on video demos to introduce not just FFmpeg, but basics of audio/video and transcoding in general. [Here is the link](https://www.udemy.com/course/ffmpeg-the-complete-guide/?referralCode=1B0CDEEB984838103727) to the course in case anyone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

Look into this roadmap which has great details on how to learn ffmpeg

https://www.tareky.com/roadmap/ffmpeg